# Proving that when $\alpha$ is a root of order $r$ in a polynomial, $y(x)=x^k e^{\alpha x}$ satisfies the same polynomial differential equation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Solution to (c)

[image]

I'm having difficulty following the solution.

First of all, why can the summations be interchanged in the second line of the solution? I mean, $\sum_{l=0}^n$ goes inside $\sum_{s=0}^k$, how is this possible? Moreover, I don't understand why the terms in brackets are $0$ because $\alpha$ is a root of (*) of order $s+a$, for each $s\le k$. I don't even see what $a$ is here.

I've been struggling to make sense of this part for a long time, and I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain this.

Comment: What book is this from, by the way?

Comment: Spivak's Calculus

Answer (score 0):

1. Interchanging summations is always possible as long as the summations are finite.
2. If $\alpha$ is a root of order $r$ of a polynomial $P$, then the derivatives $P^{(l)}(\alpha) = 0$ for all $1 \leqslant l \leqslant r - 1$. You can verify the terms in the brackets, they are the coefficients of the derivatives.